# room transaction to move multiple rows up

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I am writing an android app, where user can select multiple todos in a todo list and move them one row up. Data is stored in room. Table has a `orderId` column, used for order in the ui, like(ordered by `orderId`)

```
id(primary key)  orderId extra
32               1       ...
25               2       ...
21               3       ...
33               4       ...
37               5       ...
```

If user move up `32 21 33`, the result data should be(ordered by `orderId`)

```
id(primary key)  orderId extra
32               1       ...
21               2       ...
33               3       ...
25               4       ...
37               5       ...
```

The room transaction is like

```kotlin
@Transaction
suspend moveUp(todos: List<Todo>){
   ...
}
```

Any robust and efficient implemention?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following as the SQL for an `@Query`

:-

```
WITH
    cte_id_csv_list(c,v,r) AS (
        SELECT 0,'','32,21,33'/*<<<<<<<<<< CSV passed e.g. :csv_list_of_ids_to_move_up_in_order */||','
        UNION ALL  SELECT c+1,substr(r,1,instr(r,',')-1),substr(r,instr(r,',')+1) FROM cte_id_csv_list WHERE length(r) > 0 LIMIT 100
    ),
    cte_move_down(id,orderId,extra) AS (
        SELECT id, orderid + (select count(*) FROM cte_id_csv_list WHERE c > 0), extra FROM todo WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT v FROM cte_id_csv_list)
    ),
    cte_move_up(id,orderid,extra) AS (
        SELECT v,c,(SELECT extra FROM todo WHERE id = v)  FROM cte_id_csv_list WHERE c > 0
    ),
    cte_combined(id,orderid,extra) AS (SELECT * FROM cte_move_up UNION ALL SELECT * FROM cte_move_down),
    cte_mono(id,orderid,extra) AS (SELECT id, (SELECT count(*)+1 FROM cte_combined AS cc WHERE cc.orderid < cte_combined.orderid ORDER BY cc.orderid ASC), extra FROM cte_combined ORDER BY orderid ASC)
UPDATE todo SET orderid = (SELECT orderid FROM cte_mono WHERE todo.id = cte_mono.id);
```

- WHERE a csv of the id's is passed as the third parameter of the `SELECT` statement for the first (recursive) CTE. See the comment `/*<<<<<<<<<< ....`
- A CTE is a Common Table Expression (a temporary table), in the above there are a number of CTE's that progressively build the data to drive the UPDATE.

  - CTE's exist just for the duration of the statement that they are within.
- **cte_id_csv_list** builds rows in the table that split the the 3rd (passed but hard coded for the demo) value (the CSV of the id's to move up). In doing so they are numbered 1,2,3 .... (for as many move-ups in the list)

  - for safety sake, the LIMIT 100 restricts the number of recursions to 100 (just in case to prevent a never ending loop).
- **cte_move_down**, for rows who's id is not in cte_id_csv_list, but are in the core/underlying (todo) table adds the number of rows in cte_id_csv_list (ignoring the initial row which has c as 0 and v (the id) as nothing).
- **cte_move_up** gets the id (v) and the new orderid (c) from cte_id_csv_list and the value for the extra column from the todo table (i.e. the original value of extra).
- **cte_combined** just merges  the cte_move_up and the cte_move_down, the moves up's with the lower orderid added first.
- **cte_mono** that changes the new orders to be monotonically increasing.

Finally the UPDATE does the `"WITH"` part updating according to the data in the cte_mono CTE.

As a DEMO consider the following:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS todo;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todo (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, orderId INTEGER, extra TEXT);
INSERT INTO todo VALUES (32,1,'WAS 1'),(25,2,'WAS 2'),(21,3,'WAS 3'),(33,4,'WAS 4'),(37,5,'WAS 5');
SELECT * FROM todo ORDER BY orderid ASC;
WITH
    cte_id_csv_list(c,v,r) AS (
        SELECT 0,'','32,21,33'/*<<<<<<<<<< CSV passed e.g. :csv_list_of_ids_to_move_up_in_order */||','
        UNION ALL  SELECT c+1,substr(r,1,instr(r,',')-1),substr(r,instr(r,',')+1) FROM cte_id_csv_list WHERE length(r) > 0 LIMIT 100
    ),
    cte_move_down(id,orderId,extra) AS (
        SELECT id, orderid + (select count(*) FROM cte_id_csv_list WHERE c > 0), extra FROM todo WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT v FROM cte_id_csv_list)
    ),
    cte_move_up(id,orderid,extra) AS (
        SELECT v,c,(SELECT extra FROM todo WHERE id = v)  FROM cte_id_csv_list WHERE c > 0
    ),
    cte_combined(id,orderid,extra) AS (SELECT * FROM cte_move_up UNION ALL SELECT * FROM cte_move_down),
    cte_mono(id,orderid,extra) AS (SELECT id, (SELECT count(*)+1 FROM cte_combined AS cc WHERE cc.orderid < cte_combined.orderid ORDER BY cc.orderid ASC), extra FROM cte_combined ORDER BY orderid ASC)
UPDATE todo SET orderid = (SELECT orderid FROM cte_mono WHERE todo.id = cte_mono.id);
SELECT * FROM todo ORDER BY orderid ASC;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS todo;
```

- this can be dropped into an SQL tool and run.

> [SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9eecb7/17761)

When executed the output (todo table before and after) is:-

[image]

and then

[image]

- Note the whole thing is a single execution and thus a single transaction.